# What relation between vitality and HP max of character in FF7?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

**I search the formula between vitality carac and HP MAX?** in Final Fantasy 7

It's increased by level, but how first HP max are determined? And after how is determinated HP MAX by vitality?

Comment: Vitality doesn't share a connection with HP MAX from my understand. HP is gained independently of other stats and vitality is compared against the attackers strength to determine how much physical damage is taken

Comment: Ok, in this case, What's formula to determine HP max at start and by level?

Comment: I believe the HP Max per level is determined by (Vit/4)+1 Max HP. I know this has been the case in past final fantasy games but I can't confirm that it is true in FF7 as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's not

---

From [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/36775)

> HP Baseline = Base +  (Level - 1) * Gradient
>
> MP Baseline = Base + [(Level - 1) * Gradient / 10]

And from the same guide, here are the variables:

```
=============================================================================
        L 2-11   L12-21   L22-31   L32-41   L42-51   L52-61   L62-81   L82-99
 Char   Grd Bs   Grd Bs   Grd Bs   Grd Bs   Grd Bs   Grd Bs   Grd Bs   Grd Bs
=============================================================================
Cloud   20  15   10  16   10  16    8  17    8  17    8  17    7  18    6  19
Barret  15  14    8  15    8  15    7  15    6  16    5  17    4  18    3  20
Tifa    20  14   10  15   10  15    9  16    9  17   10  17   10  17    6  20
Aeris   18  14    8  15    8  15    8  16    8  16    5  18    7  17    7  17
Red     18  14    8  15    8  15    8  16    8  16    5  18    7  17    7  17
Yuffie  20  16   10  17   10  17   10  17    8  18   10  18   10  18    9  19
Cait    20  14   10  15   10  15    9  16    9  17   10  17   10  17    6  20
Vince   20  14   10  15   10  15    9  16    9  17   10  17   10  17    6  20
Cid     15  14    8  15    8  15    7  15    6  16    5  17    4  18    3  20
=============================================================================
```