# Formula for primary stats on level up?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I'm creating a stat level up calculator and was reading through this guide > https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/130791-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/36775

For leveling up on primary stats, it says "This difference is then capped at 0 to 11 inclusive", however I see the number can be calculated above 11 when testing with my java code...

```
    // Dexterity
    int levelUp = 7; // cloud starting level(6)
    dex = 6; // cloud starting dexterity at level 6
    baseNumber = 6; // cloud rank curve is 6 (for dex), and is within 2-11 levelUp bracket, so 6 is the number on table
    gradient = 72; // cloud rank curve is 6 (for dex), and is within 2-11 levelUp bracket, so 72 is the number on table
    baselineStat = baseNumber + ((gradient * levelUp) / 100);
    randomStatDifferenceOne = 1 + baselineStat - dex;
    randomStatDifferenceTwo = 2 + baselineStat - dex;
    randomStatDifferenceThree = 3 + baselineStat - dex;
    randomStatDifferenceFour = 4 + baselineStat - dex;
    randomStatDifferenceFive = 5 + baselineStat - dex;
    randomStatDifferenceSix = 6 + baselineStat - dex;
    randomStatDifferenceSeven = 7 + baselineStat - dex;
    randomStatDifferenceEight = 8 + baselineStat - dex;
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceOne);
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceTwo);
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceThree);
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceFour);
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceFive);
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceSix);
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceSeven);
    System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceEight);
```

This gives me the following results with Rnd(1-8):

```
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

In the guide... he has the following level up stat calculated as follows for the difference number (that should only be 0-11):

```
     *     Difference | Stat Gain
     *         0-3    |     0
     *         4-6    |     1
     *         7-9    |     2
     *        10-11   |     3
```

So my question is how is it handled when the number is above 11, or below 0(assuming below 0 is possible)?

Comment: You said it yourself, **capped**  (...) to 11.

Comment: By the way, (even though this isn't Stackoverflow): Why don't you just create a superclass for randomstatdifference or at the very least put it in an array. That code is really messy mate

Comment: You might get more responses on [Game Dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but also check their guidelines before posting your question

Comment: @oak The thing is, it's not capped at 11. I got a difference of 12 and 13. I need to know what to do with those numbers when it's higher than 11. As for the code question, this is just reference code (not the actual code in my application). It allows me to refer back to so I can see how the formula works.

Comment: But that's the thing that capped means, up to 11. If it's 12,13,999, it's 11. At least, that's what the word means. It's not that hard to check either, just compile it and cheat the game with a 9999 exp after battle cheat. You'll confirm your results

Comment: hmm, I just wanted to be sure that is how the numbers over 11 should be handled. The way his guide made it seemed is no matter how the math is done you will never see a number calculated above 11. And if that is the case, why not just cap it at 10. It would be the same thing. Seems slightly illogical.

Comment: You can always try to contact the email address at the top of the file if you don't want to test it yourself :/

Comment: I did, who knows if he will respond. That was why I also thought asking here might give me an answer, since I saw the answer was given about hp/mp > https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260227/what-relation-between-vitality-and-hp-max-of-character-in-ff7?newreg=0d7c40832e314e20afa623898f4f65c6

Comment: @Wondercricket Thanks, and will do > https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140485/formula-for-primary-stats-on-level-up-for-gamefinal-fantasy-vii